# Network Menu missing in top Menu Bar in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: networking

I have recently install 14.04 and the noticed the usual network indicator icon (little wifi icon) which allowed me to connect wifi, broadband and wired is no longer available. Is there a way of getting it back?

Comment: Please check your computers BIOS or UFEI for network options.

Comment: Did the steps in my answer help at all or resolve the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem before, here is what I did to correct it.

Open Terminal

```
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
sudo shutdown -r now
```

This SHOULD correct the icon missing

Comment: worked for me in ubuntu 16.04 LTS .